# A list of Windows rootkit detection and removal tools

Tags: windows, anti-virus, rootkit

A list of **rootkit detection and/or removal tools** from **publicly trusted sources**:

> **Name, Vendor, Latest release**
>
> [RootkitRevealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx), Sysinternals,
> November 1 2006
>
> [Rootkit Unhooker](http://www.antirootkit.com/software/RootKit-Unhooker.htm), ep_x0ff (now working at Microsoft according to [Rootkit.com](http://www.rootkit.com/blog.php?user=EP_X0FF)), December 2007
>
> [F-Secure Blacklight](http://www.f-secure.com/blacklight), F-Secure, Unknown
>
> [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/index.php), GMER, March 2009
>
> Microsoft Malicious Software Removal
> Tool, Microsoft, April 2009
>
> [IceSword](http://www.xfocus.net/tools/200509/IceSword_en1.12.rar), Unknown, September 2005

**Please add any trusted tools that you know of to the list.**

Answer (score 3):

[RootkitRevealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx)

> RootkitRevealer is an advanced rootkit
>   detection utility. It runs on Windows
>   NT 4 and higher and its output lists
>   Registry and file system API
>   discrepancies that may indicate the
>   presence of a user-mode or kernel-mode
>   rootkit. RootkitRevealer successfully
>   detects many persistent rootkits
>   including AFX, Vanquish and
>   HackerDefender (note: RootkitRevealer
>   is not intended to detect rootkits
>   like Fu that don't attempt to hide
>   their files or registry keys).

Answer (score 2):

F-secure blacklight (free, Windows)

Answer (score 1):

[GMER](http://www.gmer.net/index.php), GMER, March 2009

One of the most complete and updated scanner/fixer, I found that it could find the most rootkits, and has a steady stream of updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have had occasional success using the [Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) so that I can run an "offline" scan of the infected system.  The Achilles Heel of most well-known root kit scanners is that the root kits know about them as well. See: http://www.microsoft.com/emea/itsshowtime/sessionh.aspx?videoid=359

Answer (score 0):

[Rootkit Unhooker](http://www.antirootkit.com/software/RootKit-Unhooker.htm), ep_x0ff (now working at Microsoft), December 2007

Answer (score 0):

I like [Prevx](http://www.prevx.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For Linux:
[chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/), Pangeia Informatica (BSD Open Source) 12/17/2007
[rkhunter](http://www.rootkit.nl/projects/rootkit_hunter.html),  Rootkit.nl (GPL Open Source project) 12/31/2008

Answer (score 0):

"**ThreatExpert** is an advanced automated threat analysis system designed to analyze and report the behavior of computer viruses, worms, trojans, adware, spyware, and other security-related risks in a fully automated mode."
-- www.threatexpert.com/default.aspx

"Our free software, **Sophos Anti-Rootkit** scans, detects and removes any rootkit that is hidden on your computer using advanced rootkit detection technology." -- www.sophos.com/products/free-tools/sophos-anti-rootkit.html

"**SuperAntiSpyware**. Detect and Remove Spyware, Adware and Remove Malware, Trojans, Dialers, Worms, KeyLoggers, HiJackers, Parasites, Rootkits, Rogue Security Products and many other types of threats." -- www.superantispyware.com/

('sorry, new users aren't allowed to add hyperlinks'. Can someone edit this and activate the links please)